# nginx reverse proxy for jenkins returning a 404

Tags: nginx, http-proxy, jenkins

I have a vanilla installation of nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to run a reverse proxy in front of a Jenkins installation (running on port 8080 as bellow).

I created a conf file to be included in the default configuration and it's picking the new location fine, but it returns a 404 instead of serving the content of the application.

What am I missing? It looks exactly as in the [nginx admin guide](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse_proxy.conf

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name this_server_name;

  location /jenkins {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

ps (Edit): The 404 is being returned by Jenkins, not nginx.

Comment: Considering your PS, shouldn't you be posting your Jenkins configuration and not your `nginx` configuration?

Comment: Please rephrase your Q and try and explain the actual problem since it seems to stem from Jenkins and has nothing to do with Nginx.

Comment: Jenkins was install from apt-get. No other configuration was performed on it. If I go to the server on port 8080 I get the Jenkins application running correctly. But, if I go via the reverse proxy that I am trying to setup it returns a 404.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Nginx config

```
location /jenkins {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jenkins;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Then, reconfigure your jenkins server to accept request with /jenkins by change `JENKINS_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jenkins` to something like this

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT --prefix=/jenkins"
```

You can find details guide at

https://www.yauh.de/set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jira-and-jenkins/#usingnginxasaproxy